# Vaadin: display a list in table

Tags: list, class, vaadin

I have the need to display all values contained in a list in a table.

For example:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
    List<Rule> rules;
}
```

the result that I expect:

```
|name    |age     |rules
 alex     22       administrator, user, etc..
```

where administrator and user belong to Rule.name property

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to add a generated column and format the values from the list as you need. You can find an example [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html), just scroll down to chapter **5.16.5 Generated Table Columns**

Since you haven't posted any code, I don't know how you've setup your table. For convenience I have created a simple table with a `BeanItemContainer<Person>` and I added a 'Rules' generated column. There's room for improvement but you should get the idea:

```
    BeanItemContainer<Person> dataSource = new BeanItemContainer<Person>(Person.class);
    table_1.setContainerDataSource(dataSource);
    // create generated column and specify our "generator/formatter"
    table_1.addGeneratedColumn("rules", new RuleGenerator());
    dataSource.addAll(new ArrayList<Person>(){{add(new Person());}});
```

The formatter/generator:

```
public class RuleGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {
    @Override
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        Label label = new Label();
        StringBuilder labelContent = new StringBuilder();
        for(Rule rule : ((Person) itemId).getRules()){
           labelContent.append(rule.getName()).append(",");
        }
        label.setValue(labelContent.toString());
        return label;
    }
}
```

This is what I got:

[image: Output]

Comment: Glad to help. I think you can avoid setting the visible columns if you use as id for the generated column the same one that Vaadin is creating from the bean: `table_1.addGeneratedColumn("rules", new RuleGenerator());`. See updated example

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Vaadin 7? If yes, then use Converters. A converter is an interface that *converts* the value between datasource (in your case, collection) to presentation (in your case, string). There aren't any built-in collection <-> string converters in vaadin 7, but it is trivial to implement it yourself. Once you have implemented the converter, you can apply it on a column by calling table.setConverter(propertyId, converter);

The benefit of converters over column generators are 1) you can still sort/filter based on that column 2) you don't need to return a component, but simply a string. This creates less overhead and a lighter DOM structure that is faster for the browser to render.